# Nested dictionary comprehension (2 level)

Tags: python, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionary objects

```
data = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'parent_id': 101 ,
        'name': 'A'        
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'parent_id': 101,
        'name': 'B'        
    },
    {
        'id': 3,
        'parent_id': 102,
        'name': 'C'        
    },
    {
        'id': 4,
        'parent_id': 102,
        'name': 'D'        
    }
]
```

I want to convert this to a nested dictionary.

Structure:

```
{
    parent_id_value: {
        name_value: id_value
    }
}
```

Result of the sample list of dictionary object should be like this

```
{
    101: {
        'A': 1,
        'B': 2
    },
    102: {
        'C': 3,
        'D': 4
    }
}
```

I know we can run a `for` loop and use `setdefault` to set/get `paren_id` value and then add the name and id as key, value

```
new_dic = {}
for i in data:
    new_dic.setdefault(i['parent_id'], {})[i['name']] = i['id']
print(new_dic)
```

But I am looking for a more pythonic way, meaning is it possible through dictionary comprehension?

Answer (score 3):

So you want to play the comprehension game and you want to see a pro player at it.

Forget about itertools, forget about multiple statements. Here is the ultimate comprehension that will make any programmer working on your code throw the keyboard away and leave the room cursing you.

```
data = {parent_id: {d["name"]: d["id"] for d in [i for i in data if i["parent_id"] == parent_id]} for parent_id in set((j["parent_id"] for j in data))}
```

But for real though, don't do this in your code if it's going to be shared with someone.

Answer (score 2):

First, sort the list using [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to supply the key:

```
data.sort(key=itemgetter('parent_id'))
```

Then use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the intended sections in a nested dict-comprehension:

```
data = {
    key: {item['name']: item['id'] for item in group}
        for key, group in groupby(data, itemgetter('parent_id'))
}
```

I don't recommend writing a one-liner, but you can do it with [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
data = {
    key: {item['name']: item['id'] for item in group}
        for key, group in groupby(sorted(data, key=itemgetter('parent_id')), itemgetter('parent_id'))
}
```